# How can i remove the following consequence of Conditional Formatting?

Tags: excel

***Problem:***
[image]

Hello , as you can see in the image i want to Highlight Cells on the Column I when the cell value is less than 2. Everything works fine except those cells at the top that seem to be highlighted for no reason since they do not contain any data?. Any idea how to get rid of them??

Thank you very much for your help and time.

Comment: Can it be that in your conditional formula, you have said that it affects the other highlighted cells as well?

Comment: Highlight cells that are ">0" and "<2"

Comment: Use condition `=AND(I1<2,ROW(I1)>7)` for range `$I:$I`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom formula to do the conditional formatting (you may need to change the style dropdown to see the option to enter a formula):

```
=AND(I1<2,I1<>"")
```

If you apply this to cover your range it should work.

[image]